# Adding a new array to an array if it doesn't already exist

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have this array in layout.php

```
<?php
$arrLayout = array(
    "section1" => array(
        "wControl" => array(
            "title" => "Control",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRecentTV" => array(
            "title" => "Recent TV",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
    "section2" => array(
        "wXBMCLibrary" => array(
            "title" => "XBMC Library",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
    "section3" => array(
        "wSearch" => array(
            "title" => "Search",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRSS" => array(
            "title" => "RSS Feed",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),

);
?>
```

What I want to so is say. If ( $wControl == "true" ) and 'wControl' is not in any section then write

```
,
"wControl" => array(
            "title" => "Control",
            "display" => ""
        )
```

to the end of section x between the ) and ), and rewrite the file.

Basically wControl may or may not exist in any one of the sections. So if it doesn't exist it must be added to the array and layout.php must be rewritten to show it. Hope that all makes sense.

From what I can gather I can check if its in the array and then push it with

```
if (!in_array( wControl, $arrLayout ))  
 array_push(..)
```

How would I code this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest you use XML file for what you're doing (if that is the only content of the file). I'd be easier to use XML parser than parsing and rewriting PHP file.

Comment: Yeah that's the only content. I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param array $sections
 * @param string $name name of new key (like wControl)
 * @param mixed $value value of new key
 * @param string $into_section if empty, last section will be used
 * @return bool
 */
function addUnique(array &$sections, $name, $value, $into_section = '')
{
    $last_section = '';
    foreach ($sections as $section_name => $section)
    {
        if (key_exists($name, $section)) return false;
        $last_section = $section_name;
    }
    if (empty($into_section)) $into_section = $last_section;
    $sections[$into_section][$name] = $value;
}

$arrLayout = array(
    "section1" => array(
        "wControl" => array(
            "title" => "Control",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRecentTV" => array(
            "title" => "Recent TV",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
    "section2" => array(
        "wXBMCLibrary" => array(
            "title" => "XBMC Library",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
    "section3" => array(
        "wSearch" => array(
            "title" => "Search",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRSS" => array(
            "title" => "RSS Feed",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),

);

$wControl = true;

if ($wControl)
{
    addUnique($arrLayout, 'wControlNew', array(
                                              "title" => "Control",
                                              "display" => ""
                                         ),
              'section2');
}

var_dump($arrLayout);
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work perfectly! Can I somehow select which section it gets added to? If its gonna make it a huge hassle then no worries :)

Comment: Whats the 'section2'); for near the very bottom?

Comment: Worked it out, that's the section it must go into :)